# Getting information of a panoram in google street view python

Tags: python, google-street-view

I'm using the following url to get important information of one latitud-longitud coordinate points in google street view.

http://maps.google.com/cbk?output=xml&ll=....

Specifically I need to know what is the real coordinates for google street view for a GIVEN pair of coordinates.

In the Python API there is not how to access to this information.

For example:

http://maps.google.com/cbk?output=xml&ll=46.414382,10.013988
 For the (latitud,longitud)=(46.414382,10.013988)

This is the only way I found to do it in Python.
My question is, is it legal to use this url to get this information?

Thank you so much

Comment: What kind of information do you need?
Googlemaps provides [a python API](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) which allows accessing certain maps services

Comment: Specifically I need to know what is the real coordinates for google street view for a GIVEN pair of coordinates.
In the Python API there is not how to access to this information.

Comment: Did you look in [the terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) for google maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Google Maps API TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms): 10.4d

> No use of Content without a Google map. Unless the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits you to do so, you will not use the Content in a Maps API Implementation without a corresponding Google map. For example, you may display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map because the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits this use.

I'm not sure if the endpoint you mention is explicitly documented and use without a map is allowed somewhere in the API docs, if not, I think 10.4d applies and you are not allowed to use it.

Comment: No, unfortunatly is not documented. You're right. Thanks!